# How to concatenate the ts files with ffmpeg and python and keep the silence between the video fragments

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Using python and `ffmpeg`, I'm attempting to generate a video using photos and audio files.
There should be 1 second of silence between each video fragment. I'm adding one second to the real duration of the audio to create the silence. To do that I use `ffprobe` to acquire the audio length. All of the fragment videos are produced in the expected manner. After that, I convert them to `ts` fragments and concatenate all of the `ts` fragments I've made. The problem is that the silence I added at the end of each video fragment is removed in the final video, and the final video silence is added at the end (approx 5 sec). How can I ensure that each video fragment remains silent during concatenation?

```py
from subprocess import call, check_output
import os

FFMPEG_NAME = 'ffmpeg'

def ffmpeg_call(image_path, audio_path, temp_path, i):
    out_path_mp4 = os.path.join(temp_path, f'frame_{i}.mp4')
    out_path_ts = os.path.join(temp_path, f'frame_{i}.ts')
    audio_duration = str(float(check_output(['ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-of', 'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1', audio_path]).decode('utf-8')) + 1)
    call([FFMPEG_NAME, '-loop', '1', '-y', '-i', image_path, '-i', audio_path,
          '-c:v', 'libx264', '-c:a', 'aac',
          '-b:a', '192k', '-vf', 'crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2', '-shortest', '-t', audio_duration, out_path_mp4])
    call([FFMPEG_NAME, '-y', '-i', out_path_mp4, '-c', 'copy',
          '-bsf:v', 'h264_mp4toannexb', '-f', 'mpegts', out_path_ts])


def ffmpeg_concat(video_list_str, out_path):
    call([FFMPEG_NAME, '-y', '-f', 'mpegts', '-i', f'{video_list_str}',
          '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:a', 'aac_adtstoasc', out_path])

def create_video(temp_dir_path, audio_paths_list):
    image_name = 'image_3.jpg'
    output_path = os.path.join(temp_dir_path, 'main.mp4')
    for idx, audio_path in enumerate(audio_paths_list):
        image_path = os.path.join(temp_dir_path, image_name)
        audio_path = os.path.join(temp_dir_path, audio_path)
        ffmpeg_call(image_path, audio_path, temp_dir_path, idx)

    video_list = [os.path.join(temp_dir_path, f'frame_{i}.ts') \
                  for i in range(len(audio_paths_list))]
    video_list_str = 'concat:' + '|'.join(video_list)
    ffmpeg_concat(video_list_str, output_path)



def main():
    temp_dir_path = '/var/folder/1'
    audio_list = ['audio1.mp3', 'audio2.mp3', 'audio3.mp3']
    create_video(temp_dir_path, audio_list)
    print('finished')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I would rather use [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) with [ImageClip](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html#imageclip) and [AudioFileClip](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/AudioClip.html#audiofileclip) (and `AudioClip` for silence)

Comment: @furas Indeed, yes. Pretty good library, but even in docs they say that for these purposes it is better to use ffmpeg directly

Comment: Silence is ignored likely because of the `-shortest` argument. The video is likely 1 second shorter than the padded audio. You need to concat `color` video frames to the video stream to match the length.